# Calculations involving pgfkeys?

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfmath

I've begun using pgfkeys to set a bunch of custom variables.  I'm also using pgfmath to do some calculations.  I understand how to set and call the variables, but the manual is mind boggling to me, and I can't figure out whether or how to use these features in tandem.  I would like use a command to update a variable, in the manner of "n + #1 = n".  Are there some keywords I should search for, to get me on the right path?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can imagine what your use case is. In general, if you define some key such as `\tikzset{ my key/.initial={5} }`, then you can use this like `\pgfmathparse{ 1 + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my key} }\pgfmathresult`, and the output will be "6.0". But I am unsure whether this is what you mean ...

Comment: There's no built-in way to do math on a value of a key. You could however create your own handler, say `.add to value` that performs the evaluation of `<key> + #1` and stores the result back in `<key>`. You could also define a handler where you could provide any formula where `#1` stands for the value of the key. This would allow `my key/.do math={#1+1}` to keep with @JasperHabicht's example.

Comment: There's already the `.evaluated` handler which would have you do `my key/.evaluated=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my key}+1`.